# python fernet - decrypt exception InvalidToken - user login authentication

Tags: python, encryption, fernet

I am trying to implement the solution (encryption of data with password) provided in the fernet docs under [Using passwords with Fernet](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/?highlight=decrypt#using-passwords-with-fernet).

Since I would also like to use the same password for **user login authentication** I would like to know **if it is safe to assume** that if the encrypted data can't be decrypted with another (e.g. false) password, since I get the exception cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken, **that also the user authentication failed because the provided password does not match the password used to encrypt the data**?

In other words, do I need to check the authentication also using a separate logic with an implementation of a hashed password or can I rely solely on the fernet exception cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken for this?